# Energy level of hybrid orbitals in the molecular orbital energy diagram

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, orbitals

I would like to know what is the level of energy of a hybrid orbital?

For instance, lets consider the $\ce{N2}$ molecule. According to its geometry, we know that there is an orbital *2p* and *2s* that are going to form 2 *sp* orbitals.
 In the molecular orbital energy diagram, where should we place the these 2 *sp* orbitals? Would they be in the middle of a *2p* and a *2s*? And which *p* orbital do we take to take the middle ($p_x$,$p_y$,$p_z$, $\pi$ or $\sigma$?) Will the *sp** be higher or lower that the *$2p_x$* and *$2p_y$*?

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Since you already took the tour, all that remains is to point you towards the [help], where any unclear aspects of how the site works will be explained =)

Comment: Note that molecular orbital theory does not require hybrid orbitals.

Comment: Right, I did not know that molecular orbital theory does not require the use of hybrid orbitals, cheers.

Comment: @Bbruyne If you decide to use hybrid orbitals then, yes, your guess is correct: Since an $\mathrm{sp}$ orbital is an equal mixture of an $\mathrm{s}$ and a $\mathrm{p}$ orbital it would be energetically in the middle between those orbitals. For the mixing you would usually use the $\mathrm{p}$ orbital that points in the direction of the bonding axis which conventially is taken to be the $\mathrm{p}_{z}$ orbital.

Comment: @Bbruyne What do you mean by $\mathrm{sp}^{*}$? There is no such thing as an anti-bonding $\mathrm{sp}$ orbital if that is what you mean. Mixing orbitals to form hybrid orbitals is conceptually totally different from letting, say, two $\mathrm{s}$ orbitals interact to form a $\sigma$ and a $\sigma^{*}$ orbital.

Comment: I assume that each **sp** orbital of the two *N* will interact to form a  σ and a σ\* orbital.

Comment: @Bbruyne Yes, the two $\mathrm{sp}$ orbitals pointing towards each other would form form a $\sigma$ and a $\sigma^{*}$ orbital. The $\mathrm{sp}$ orbitals pointing away from each other would interact as well but much weaker due to the low orbital overlap. Thus the splitting between the resulting $\sigma$ and $\sigma^{*}$ orbitals would be quite small and so those $\mathrm{sp}$ orbitals could essentially be considered as non-bonding orbitals (holding the $\ce{N2}$ lone pairs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we have an *sp* hybrid orbital, it is usually made of the *s* orbital and the *p* orbital that points in the bounding axis ($p_z$). It's energy will be the mean of the energy of the initial orbitals.

In the example of $\ce{N2}$, it is essential to bear in mind that each *sp* won't form an $\sigma$ and an $\sigma^*$ orbital. Only the one pair of the *sp* orbitals, the one that overlap the most, will do. The other pair will contribute to the $\ce{N2}$ lone pairs because there is nearly no overlapping. The 2 others bonds that form the triple bonds are made with the 2 left orbitals $p_x$ and $p_y$.

By the way, it is not necessary to use hybrid orbitals for the molecular orbital theory.

Credits to [Philipp](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/189/philipp) and [Ben Norris](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/275/ben-norris).

Comment: "Its energy will be the mean of the energy of the initial orbitals" How does this align with the answer posted here? https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41097/why-does-the-mixing-of-sigma-2s-and-2p-orbitals-lower-the-energy-of-the-sigma-2s?rq=1